# change the style and theme of android app

Tags: android, coding-style

From the beging The android app has black background, I want to make all these changes, How is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app's manifest, use something like

`<activity android:name="com.troj.yourapp"

            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">`

if you want to apply a different standard Android (or even custom) theme.

Otherwise, you could just set the `background`-property of your layout in `res/layout/yourlayout.xml`